# Downloading The Offline HelpContentSetup.msha

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is it possible to download the `HelpContentSetup.msha` for VS2010 while offline? Because my `HelpContentSetup.msha` is corrupt and I can not install it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer in this link : http://tntcube.in/msdn-offline-visual-studio-2010/
Or simply search and download "VS 2010 Help Downloader" (its a tool), which is an external tool which allows you to download the Help file package independently.